# Code prompts the user to input numbers twice and then displays results (python)

Tags: python-3.x

CODE

```
def main():

    numbers()

    add()

    display()


def numbers():

    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    num2 = int(input("Enter another number: "))

    return num1,num2


def add():

    num1,num2 = numbers()

    print(num1,"and",num2,"=",num1 + num2)


def display():

    num1,num2 = numbers()

    print("The numbers that you chose are",num1,"and",num2)

    print("Both numbers added equal :", num1+num2)

main()
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter a number: 22

Enter another number: 22

Enter a number: 22

Enter another number: 22

22 and 22 = 44

Enter a number: 22

Enter another number: 22

The numbers that you chose are 22 and 22

Both numbers added equal : 44
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: How can i get it to only ask for the two numbers once?

Comment: You call numbers() twice. Once in main(), and once in add().

Comment: Actually, you only need to call the display() function in main, then it should be fine :)

Comment: You should look into how you pass values to a function.